# PostgreSQL C extension compiling under Visual Studio

Tags: c, postgresql, visual-studio, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to compile test extension for PostgreSQL under Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition 2017. I follow the tutorial from https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/ but I've got some problems (extension code as from the site).

First of all, after configuration and first compiling, I've got the error:

```
missing strings.h
```

coming from `c.h` in `include\postgresql\server` After some reading I've change the include declaration to `string.h`. Then it stops me at the same header file with message:

`cannot use __int128 in this architecture`

It should go smoothly, am I missing something? I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.5 x64 from BigSQL installer, SDK Version is 10.0.16299.0, compiling the extension to both x32 and x64 platforms have the same effect.

Comment: Probably a missing compiler flag. Is the community edition crippled in any way?

Comment: From the link you provided: _If you’re trying to compile a 64-bit extension these instructions will work with minimal changes, but be aware that many free Visual Studio versions do not include a 64-bit toolchain. To test 64-bit builds I landed up installing the Windows SDK 7.1 plus the 64-bit toolchain patches for it, then selecting “WindowsSDK7.1” under Configuration Properties -> General -> Platform Toolkit in project properties._

Comment: @jwdonahue It's my first time with it, just have installed it out of the box with everything needed to compile c\c++ projects